# Receive JSON Variables using Jersey sent from and Android device using HttpPost

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey

I have an Android code for sending data using HttpPost :

```
public static void sendRideIdAndEmail(String rideId,String email){
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
    HttpResponse response;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.59/FareShareREST/api/rides/joinRide");
        json.put("rideid", rideId);
        json.put("emailid", email);
        Log.v("RideEmailJson",json.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);

        /*Checking response */
        if(response!=null){
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
    }

}
```

I have a RestFul Post Method on Server side running on Tomcat 7 :

```
   @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("joinRide")
public Response joinRide(@PathParam("rideid") long rideid,@PathParam("emailid") String     emailid) {
    System.out.println(emailid);
    Ride ride=rideRepository.getRideById(rideid);
    UserDetail userDetail=userRepository.getUserDetailbyEmailId(emailid);
    User user=new User();
    user.setName(userDetail.getName());
    user.setRegistrationId(userDetail.getRegistrationId());
    rideRepository.addUserToRide(ride, user);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

But I always receive email id as null.I have tried using @FormParam. But that to seem to be not working.

Can someone provide me with any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path parameters (`@PathParam`) are extracted from the incoming request URL. So, for example, with the URL `http://192.168.1.59/FareShareREST/api/rides/joinRide/5` and the following code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/joinRide/{rideid}")
public Response joinRide(@PathParam("rideid") long rideid) {
    System.out.println(rideid);
}
```

You would get `rideid` mapped to `5`. The value of `5` comes from the portion of the URL that was mapped (`/joinRide/{id}`). ***But***, this is not useful for your scenario - you are creating a JSON object and including it in the request body. In this scenario, on the server side, the JAX-RS provider will map this request body to the first eligible parameter on your resource method. You want code similar to this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/joinRide")
public Response joinRide(String json) {
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

This will set your JSON string directly into the variable so smartly named `json`. Of course, you would need to parse the JSON to get at the data in it, which you might not want to do. In this case, create a simple POJO containing your expected data fields, and use that in your resource method:

```
public class EmailInfo implements Serializable {
    private String rideId;
    private String email;

    // Constructors, Getters/Setters
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/joinRide")
public Response joinRide(EmailInfo info) {
    System.out.println(info.getRideId());
    System.out.println(info.getEmail());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I wanted to pass only variables in POST which can be recieved at serverSide. I there any way

Comment: Ok, so your server side is fixed, but you can change the client side?

Comment: I just want to post variables from my android app. So that it can be received on Server

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. If you can't change the server side then you will need to append those variables you are trying to pass, to the URL (e.g: http://192.168.1.59/FareShareREST/api/rides/joinRide/5/bob@foo.com). Note that you will have to encode the URL because of the email address in it. On the other hand, if you can change the server side then go over my answer and modify your code to match.

Comment: Ok. Then I will preferable make a Wrapper Class like EmailInfo and do it. Thanks